Unable to make curl requests to _users database in couchdb
in the past i've once deleted the _users database i don't know why. I recreated the database using curl But now it seems like i can no longer add users using curl or node into _users database. e.g:
curl -X PUT http://{username}:{userpassword}@localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jack \
         -H "Accept: application/json" \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -d '{
           "name": "jack",
           "password": "apple",
           "roles": ["owner"],
           "type": "user"
         }'
{"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error"}


I've tried to reinstall everything and tried to modify the JavaScript validation in the auth document but I'm not winning.
